# NativeScript Vue - how would I go about adding using a native iOS NSObject such as SKStoreReviewController?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have checked out a few plugins and most/all are not for NativeScript Vue and don't work as expected with Apple's current way of rating apps with the star rating prompt ( SKStoreReviewController https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller ) .  They use the old (pre IOS 10.3) way of using UIAlertView.
Is there a way to import SKStoreReviewController in?  I only really need to call `requestReview()` on once it's accessible.